# Is it okay to send large array through Intent?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, storage

I want to send large array from one intent to another. The array contains so many elements(about 50-100). So I want to know if it is a good programming practice to send large arrays like those through intents. Will it effect the performance of my app in anyway?

Comment: How you manipulate this 50-100 data ? If it is from any local database or file, it would be better if you can do the same read operation on the second view also

Comment: I have built a custom list view. Each list item contains different images. So for this purpose I have stored the reference to these images in Integer[] array so as to use them in the custom list view with ease.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it effects on performance and directly proportional to  the size of intent data , 
mobile device has small heap size and in intent data still in activity object till destroy ,
intent is basically for loss coupling in java code for activity classes .

Answer (score -1):

You can save that data in singleton class and grab it from second Activity.